# Iterate over ArrayList of ArrayLists using JSTL

Tags: jstl

I have an arrayList (mainList) of arrayLists (personalList,c1List,c2List) in my searchUser method.

```
  public List<List<UserApplication>> searchUser(EdsStudentForm eds) throws Exception {

    //My arraylist constructors    
    List<List<UserApplication>> mainList = new ArrayList<List<UserApplication>>();
    List<UserApplication> personalList = new ArrayList<UserApplication>();
    List<UserApplication> c1List = new ArrayList<UserApplication>();
    List<UserApplication> c2List = new ArrayList<UserApplication>();
    List<UserApplication> c3List = new ArrayList<UserApplication>();

    String searchPersonalQuery = "SELECT studentCode,title,firstName,lastName,"
            + "streetNumber,streetName,suite,city,province,country,postalCode,email,"
            + "workPhone,cellPhone,homePhone,sin "
            + "FROM studtregister_personal WHERE studentCode=?";
    String searchCourse1Query = "SELECT programCode1,lang1,schDays1,schTime1,schType1,"
            + "totalHours1,startDate1,pricetype1,price1 "
            + "FROM studtregister_course1 WHERE studentCode=?";
    String searchCourse2Query = "SELECT programCode2,lang2,schDays2,schTime2,schType2,"
            + "totalHours2,startDate2,pricetype2,price2 "
            + "FROM studtregister_course2 WHERE studentCode=?";
    String searchCourse3Query = "SELECT programCode3,lang3,schDays3,schTime3,schType3,"
            + "totalHours3,startDate3,pricetype3,price3 "
            + "FROM studtregister_course3 WHERE studentCode=?";

    int stCode = eds.getStudentCode();

    try {
        currentCon = ConnectionManager.getDBConnection();
        PreparedStatement pst1 = currentCon.prepareStatement(searchPersonalQuery);
        pst1.setInt(1, stCode);
        rs = pst1.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            UserApplication personBean = new UserApplication();
            personBean.setStudentCode(rs.getInt(1));
            personBean.setTitle(rs.getString(2));
            personBean.setFirstName(rs.getString(3));
            personBean.setLastName(rs.getString(4));
            personBean.setStreetNumber(rs.getString(5));
            personBean.setStreetName(rs.getString(6));
            personBean.setSuite(rs.getString(7));
            personBean.setCity(rs.getString(8));
            personBean.setProvince(rs.getString(9));
            personBean.setCountry(rs.getString(10));
            personBean.setPostalCode(rs.getString(11));
            personBean.setEmail(rs.getString(12));
            personBean.setWorkPhone(rs.getString(13));
            personBean.setCellPhone(rs.getString(14));
            personBean.setHomePhone(rs.getString(15));
            personBean.setSin(rs.getString(16));
            personalList.add(personBean);
        }

        pst1.close();

        currentCon = ConnectionManager.getDBConnection();
        PreparedStatement pst2 = currentCon.prepareStatement(searchCourse1Query);
        pst2.setInt(1, stCode);
        rs = pst2.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            UserApplication C1Bean = new UserApplication();
            C1Bean.setProgramCode1(rs.getString(1));
            C1Bean.setLanguage1(rs.getString(2));
            C1Bean.setScheduleDay1(rs.getString(3));
            C1Bean.setScheduleTime1(rs.getString(4));
            C1Bean.setScheduleType1(rs.getString(5));
            C1Bean.setTotalHours1(rs.getString(6));
            C1Bean.setStartDate1(rs.getString(7));
            C1Bean.setPriceType1(rs.getString(8));
            C1Bean.setPrice1(rs.getString(9));
            c1List.add(C1Bean);
        }

        pst2.close();

        currentCon = ConnectionManager.getDBConnection();
        PreparedStatement pst3 = currentCon.prepareStatement(searchCourse2Query);
        pst3.setInt(1, stCode);
        rs = pst3.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            UserApplication C2Bean = new UserApplication();
            C2Bean.setProgramCode2(rs.getString(1));
            C2Bean.setLanguage2(rs.getString(2));
            C2Bean.setScheduleDay2(rs.getString(3));
            C2Bean.setScheduleTime2(rs.getString(4));
            C2Bean.setScheduleType2(rs.getString(5));
            C2Bean.setTotalHours2(rs.getString(6));
            C2Bean.setStartDate2(rs.getString(7));
            C2Bean.setPriceType2(rs.getString(8));
            C2Bean.setPrice2(rs.getString(9));
            c2List.add(C2Bean);
        }

        pst3.close();

        currentCon = ConnectionManager.getDBConnection();
        PreparedStatement pst4 = currentCon.prepareStatement(searchCourse3Query);
        pst4.setInt(1, stCode);
        rs = pst4.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            UserApplication C3Bean = new UserApplication();
            C3Bean.setProgramCode3(rs.getString(1));
            C3Bean.setLanguage3(rs.getString(2));
            C3Bean.setScheduleDay3(rs.getString(3));
            C3Bean.setScheduleTime3(rs.getString(4));
            C3Bean.setScheduleType3(rs.getString(5));
            C3Bean.setTotalHours3(rs.getString(6));
            C3Bean.setStartDate3(rs.getString(7));
            C3Bean.setPriceType3(rs.getString(8));
            C3Bean.setPrice3(rs.getString(9));
            c3List.add(C3Bean);
        }

        pst4.close();

        if(personalList != null && !personalList.isEmpty()) {
            mainList.add(personalList);
        }
        if(c1List != null && !c1List.isEmpty()) {
            mainList.add(c1List);
        }
        if(c2List != null && !c2List.isEmpty()) {
            mainList.add(c2List);
        }
        if(c3List != null && !c3List.isEmpty()) {
            mainList.add(c3List);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ee) {
        System.out.println("Unable to connect to database:student_registration");
        ee.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (currentCon != null) {
                currentCon.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return mainList;
}
```

In my struts actionclass,I put the mainList arrayList in session:

```
  public ActionForward edit(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,               HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

    if (null == session.getAttribute("username")) {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    } else {
        EdsStudentForm eds = (EdsStudentForm) form;
        try {
            List<List<UserApplication>> mainList = uaDAO.searchUser(eds);
            if (!mainList.isEmpty()) {
                request.getSession().setAttribute("mainList", mainList);
                action_forward = EDITSUCCESS;
            } else {
                action_forward = EDITFAILURE;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
   return mapping.findForward(action_forward);
}
```

However,when I try to iterate over the arrayList in my jsp file with the following code :

```
    <html:form method="post">
        <table>
            <c:forEach items="${mainList}" var ="uList">
                <c:forEach items="${uList}" var="pList">
                <tr> 
                    <td><label>Student Code : </label></td>
                    <td><a href="editStudt.jsp"><c:out value="${pList.studentCode}"></c:out></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>First Name : </label></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${pList.firstName}"></c:out></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>Last Name : </label></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${pList.lastName}"></c:out></td>

                    </tr> 
                </c:forEach>
            </c:forEach>
      </table>
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Main Menu" onclick="doMenu()"/>
    </html:form>
```

I get the right info printed out...3 - 4 times(depending on whether I have 3 or 4 arrayLists in mainList.

```
  The output :

  Student code : 900
  First Name : XYZ
  Last Name : XYZ

  Student code : 900
  First Name : XYZ
  Last Name : XYZ

  Student code : 900
  First Name : XYZ
  Last Name : XYZ
```

Can you pls tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's impossible to say without more information and a more clearly-worded question. It's likely your list population code is incorrect, perhaps you're using the same list reference for the inner lists: is the info you're seeing the last info added?

Comment: I'm seeing all my information printed out correctly,it's just that it's printed out three time.

Comment: It's impossible to say without more information. It's only going to print out what's in the lists.

Comment: I'ved edited my question.Could you pls take a look? I suppose it's becoz I have 3 arrayLists in the main arrayList and hence it gets iterated over 3 times.....perhaps I'm using arrayList of arrayLists in the wrong way.Thanks for answering:)

Answer (score 0):

Because you added 3 variables to the first list

Answer (score 0):

You have only a single instance of `UserApplication`:

```
UserApplication sBean = new UserApplication();
while (rs.next()) {
    ...
```

You need to create a *new* `UserApplication` for *each* item in the result set:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    UserApplication sBean = new UserApplication();
    ...
```

That's why I asked about showing the same data multiple times, which it *must* be if this is the actual code. All you did was change the instance's data and re-add the *same bean* to the list.

Comment: student code : 900 first name : XYZ  last name : XYZ  student code : 0 first name : (nothing) last name: ( nothing) student code: 0 first name : (nothing) last name: (nothing)

Comment: @javaStudent It's impossible to understand what you're doing or why unless you tell us. Obviously either the data is wrong, or you're creating the lists wrong, or...? The code doesn't care what data is in the lists: it will iterate over whatever is present.

Comment: sorry about that,I've put all my code up.Thanks for your quick responses.

Comment: @javaStudent We also can't see your data. To be honest, I don't understand what the issue is: you can look at your data, you can trace/step through your code. You have all the tools necessary to find out where the issue is. Also, it's likely the list should be in the request, not the session, but I don't know what else you do with it.